# Sending file[type="file"] multiple content as list of base64's

Tags: javascript

There is a code that takes all files from input of multiple files, gets base64 for each of them, packs to array and jsonifies it. How to simplify and improve quality of code?

```
text = $('#input-' + id).val();
var files = document.querySelector('#files' + id + ' > input[type=file]').files;
if (text != '' || files.length > 0) {
    var files_obj = [];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
        var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
        files_obj.push(btoa(binaryString));
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        reader.readAsBinaryString(files[i]);
    }
    while (files_obj.length < files.length) {}
    $('input[type="file"]').val("");
    files_json = JSON.stringify(files_obj);
    json = '{"action": "message", "from": ' + userId + ', "text": "' + text + '", "room": ' + id + ', "files": ' + files_json + '}';
    socket.send(json);
    $('#input-' + id).val("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (files_obj.length < files.length) {}
```

That's not the correct way to wait for the `FileReader`. `onload` will get called whenever a file has been successfully read, so you can check for `files.length` there, and call the rest of the function as needed. Right now you're spin-looping during at least partly CPU intensive (base64 encoding) operations. Which is a huge waste.